# Can I use IsNothing along with the Lookup function

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to use the row visibility function in Report Builder 3.0 by using the expression below:

=IIF(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!Activity.Value,Fields!Activity.Value,Fields!Pred_Activity.Value,"ds_Pred"),True,False)

When I run the report, I get an error message Too many arguments to Public Function isNothing.

Is it possible to use the IsNothing function along with the Lookup function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parenthesis don't line up there for starters, if I'm reading your code correctly, what it should say is: `=IIF(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!Activity.Value,Fields!Activity.Value,Fields!Pred_Activity.Value,"ds_Pred")),True,False)`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. The formula was missing the last parenthesis. It should have been:

=IIF(IsNothing(Lookup(Fields!Activity.Value,Fields!Activity.Value,Fields!Pred_Activity.Value,"ds_Pred")),True,False)